How to change the MTAudioProcessingTap's process buffer size
The MTAudioProcessingTap will give a buffer size, it is 4096 in my situation. But I hope the buffer size and be smaller like 512 or 2048
I tried set the AVAudioSession.preferredIOBufferDurationWith(0.005) (I see in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616589-setpreferrediobufferduration?language=objc) , But it's not working..

What are you tapping?

I use AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters.audioTapProcessor to tap

Why do you need a smaller buffer? And what class are you using this with? AVAssetExportSession, AVAssetReaderOutput or AVPlayerItem?

The smaller buffer size, more MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback will be called so that I can get more  accurate timeRange from MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio and process audio buffer in this CMTimeRange When I use AVPlayerItem to play the audio, the buffer size is 4096, but when I export audio with AVAssetReaderOutput , the buffer size becomes 512... I want all of them is 512....

Any advice for this quesion?

You could abandon AVPlayerItem as your audio player.

Emm What player should I use？ I have a AVMutableComposition and a AVAudioMix to generate audio sequence....AudioPlayer seems can't work for this...

A custom player I guess. Hang on - can't you pretend that your 4096 frame buffer is actually 8 512 frame buffers?

Emm Can I divide the audioBufferList to smaller size? and process them?

The MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback paas a UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, how can I divide it into several parts to process, so that timeRange for per part will be smaller..
